# Field does not exist error when inheriting account.invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Using Odoo 10 (fetched from GitHub commit [`7413b26`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/7413b2624c6554bf641c2426c45c70fd59bc7490), branch `10.0`), installing a module which I'm porting over from Odoo 8 fails due to not finding a field in an inherited `account.invoice`. Problem is, this field *is* created within the inherited model, and the problem persists down to the point of being able to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the behavior:

`invoice.py`:

```py
from odoo import fields, models
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    a = fields.Char()
```

`invoice.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="account_invoice_form_view">
            <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="origin" position="after" >
                    <field name="a" />
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The `__manifest__.py` is `{'name':'Invoice bug','depends':['account'],'data':['invoice.xml'],'installable':True}` and `__init__.py` is just the usual `import invoice`.

Such code fails with a

```
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint
Field `a` does not exist
Error context:
View `account.invoice.form`
[view_id: 554, xml_id: invoice_bug.account_invoice_form_view, model: account.invoice, parent_id: 421]
None" while parsing /odoo/addons/invoice_bug/invoice.xml:4, near
[XML follows]
```

Here are some more observations:

- Inheriting another model and view, such as `product.template` and view `product.product_template_only_form_view` (with `<field name="default_code" position="after">`, works properly
- Using `<xpath expr="//field[@name='origin']" position="after">` instead of a `field position="after"` does not affect the error
- Other modules, such as the native `sale` module, succeeds in extending `account.invoice` and the same view (`account.invoice_form`) properly:  [sale/models/account_invoice.py:8](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7413b2624c6554bf641c2426c45c70fd59bc7490/addons/sale/models/account_invoice.py#L8), [sale/views/sale_views.xml:653](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7413b2624c6554bf641c2426c45c70fd59bc7490/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L653)
- A [similar bug exists since OpenERP 7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/1026578)
- An Odoo forum member seemingly [had the same problem](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-add-columns-to-account-invoice-new-api-72798) with Odoo 8 or 9 (the provided example leads to the same error, provided you replace the now-deleted reference to `period_id` with `date`)
- The bug triggers regardless of installed modules or stored records (tested on a clean DB + 3 other installs)

Is my code wrong, or is there a workaround ?

Comment: Did you checked the database whether field a is added in table account_invoice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**origin** field is available in **account.invoice** and **account.invoice.line** model.

If you check in form view **invoice_form** then we are getting 2 times origin fields.

1. **invoice_line_ids** in-line tree view.
2. Other info page.

If we write field position after then system will find first field inside **invoice_line_ids** in-line tree view, due to that reason we are getting error.

But Odoo is giving wrong error message.

You need to follow below xpath.

```xml
<xpath expr="//page[@name='other_info']/group/group[2]/field[@name='origin']" position="after">
    <field name="a"/>               
</xpath>
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is good the field should be added to your  model.
The one explanation for your problem is odoo didn't reach your code.

Do you have only one init file in your project or you are using multi folder project.  Check your indentation.

Comment: The example is a minimal one and consists only of the files I mentioned. Moreover, the Python code *is* reached since adding debug `print()` calls outputs text on `stdout`.

Comment: and when you check the field in developer mode it's not there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tags

```
<openerp>..</openerp> to <odoo>..</odoo>
```

Comment: Invalid. Error is not related with *<openerp>* tag